# How to create a theme plan for an online resume project using Vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

I used Vue to create an online resume project

Component splitting has been done for each part of the resume, and the theme switching is to add different class names and write separate styles

Do you have any good theme plans? seek help
[image]

[git address](https://github.com/Jeffrey-mu/resume-vue)

Give me some advice And project optimization suggestions

Comment: can you explain what a "theme plan" is - also where you separate styles are

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Similar to switching different skins